# Entity Framework batch Update-Database with connection string

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, nuget

I have a Visual Studio-solution with four Entity Framework Code First-projects. I deploy the projects frequently to multiple environments, and so use multiple connection strings.

So if I need to update all my environments I do the following for one of the projects:

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose -StartupProjectName "Sln.DataAccess1" -ConnectionStringName "DevContext"
PM> Update-Database -Verbose -StartupProjectName "Sln.DataAccess1" -ConnectionStringName "TestContext"
PM> Update-Database -Verbose -StartupProjectName "Sln.DataAccess1" -ConnectionStringName "DemoContext"
PM> Update-Database -Verbose -StartupProjectName "Sln.DataAccess1" -ConnectionStringName "StagingContext"
```

And you can imagine the continuation for Sln.DataAccess2, Sln.DataAccess3 and Sln.DataAccess4...

Is there an easier way to do this? For example to run all at the same time? I haven't found a solution for this.

No, I do not want to use EF:s automatic updating the database with a initializer like this `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DbContext>());`.

(I wouldn't mind having a GUI, just pointing out which connection string to use for which project, because it's a lot of copy and paste right now. But best would be to have an `Update-Database-All` command, for running all at the same time somehow.)

Comment: Are you deploying a web application? Web.config settings can be changed as part of the process http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Well yes, but I'd like to be able to deploy database and Web-files separately.

Comment: Won't that tend to break the application?

Comment: Well often we just change Seed-data, or something simple - and we don't want to kickstart the entire publish web process (we build+deploy through TFS). I still want to "feel" I have control over database and web app separately :)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a custom Nuget Package as explained in [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/19/writing-a-nuget-package-that-adds-a-command-to-the.aspx/) post by Phil Haack. The init.ps1 file contained these two lines:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package)
Import-Module (Join-Path $toolsPath CodeFile1.psm1)
```

And the CodeFile1.psm1 file:

```
function update-all-db
{
    Write-Host "Update all database contexts"
    update-database -ConfigurationTypeName MyProject.Web.Migrations.IdentityDb.Configuration
    update-database -ConfigurationTypeName MyProject.Web.Migrations.OtherDb.Configuration 
}

Export-ModuleMember update-all-db
```

Install the package into your project and call the update-all-db command from the Package Manager Console.